# BroadcastReceiver onReceive being called multiple times

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I'm writing an app that checks external storage state. For monitoring the state I use BroadcastReceiver and I've noticed, that onReceive is called multiple times (eg.: 3x for unmount and 1x for mount) for one event (eg.: unplug usb).

Here is my code:

```
 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    final static String TAG = "BroadcastReceiverDemo";

    private IntentFilter filter;
    private BroadcastReceiver receiver;

    private void registerReceiver() {
        filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_UNMOUNTED);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_REMOVED);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SHARED);
        filter.addDataScheme("file");
        filter.setPriority(IntentFilter.SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY);

        receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String broadcast;

                String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

                Log.d(TAG, "State: " + state);

                if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) && !Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
                    broadcast = "External storage aviable";
                } else {
                    broadcast = "External storage NOT aviable";
                }

                String msg = intent.getAction() + " received broadcast: " + broadcast;

                Log.d(TAG, msg);
            }
        };

        this.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        registerReceiver();
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        if (receiver != null) {
            this.unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        }
        super.finalize();

    }
}
```

**Q: Why is onReceive called so many times and how to make it call only once?**

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I would imagine that at least two times the receiver would be called because of ACTION_MEDIA_UNMOUNTED and ACTION_MEDIA_REMOVED. But do a simple verification and print or log the intent that the receiver received and you can see better what is going on.

Comment: I already did this and it seems that when I share my sdcard (connect to PC via USB) that creates ACTION_MEDIA_UNMOUNTED and then ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED. So receiver is called two times (once for unmounted and once for mounted action). But when I unmount sd card via Settings->Storage->Unmount I receive multiple (not 100% sure but there were four) ACTION_MEDIA_UNMOUNTED.

Comment: have you found solution now?

Comment: Sadly I haven't found the reason for this behavior. Instead I suggest workaround using boolean. So when you receive ACTION_MEDIA_UNMOUNTED set your boolean isMounted=false and when you receive ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED set isMounted=true. If the value of isMounted has changed start/stop the job.